# Incremental change from predictor variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

Sample Data

```
A   B       C           D   E
1   2016    94.49433733 2   81.28
5   2016    95.38104534 4   139.6944
7   2016    95.43885385 1   69.11
8   2016    94.91936704 1   7.23
9   2016    95.21859776 3   152.31
10  2016    95.15797535 1   86.32
11  2016    95.1830432  2   38.24
13  2016    94.01256633 2   33.3
```

Given the sample data and using R, I want to build a sequence that gives me the incremental impact from my predictor variable (**C**).

Expected Table (increment by 0.5):

```
C           ANSWER
85          
85.05       
85.1        
85.15       
85.2        
85.25       
85.3        
85.35
```

I am looking to understand for every delta change (increase) in C, what happens to D?

Here is what I tried with transform and apply

```
transform(df, volumen=unlist(tapply(C, D,  function(x) c(0, diff(x)))))
```

Comment: Do you want to do linear regression perhaps?

Comment: I have tried an lm model with those 2 variables like so `lm(S ~ D)` but how can I put together a table that shows the change using the equation from that model?

Answer (score 0):

```
fit <- lm(D ~ C, data = my_sample_data) #Fits a linear model
my_sequence <- seq(from = 85, to = 85.35, by = 0.05 ) # first column
result <- fit$coefficients[1] + my_sequence * fit$coefficients[2] #2nd column
df <- data.frame(C = my_sequence, ANSWER = result) #Makes a table
```

Comment: Do you mean for your first line, `fit <- lm(E ~ C, data = my_sample_data)`?

Comment: Or use `predict`.

Comment: @Axeman I was able to use predict and things worked out. `predict(fit, newdata=pred.data))`

Comment: @Warz You're right. We should be predicting D from C, not E from C. I've updated my code.